# Order by count in Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have two classes related via a **OneToMany** bidirectional relationship. For every subscription a new line will be added to **Subscriptions** table. I want to get the training list ordered by max subscription number.  Here are my entities:

### Trainings Entity:

```
class Trainings
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Subscriptions", mappedBy="id_training")
     */
    private $subscriptions_lists;

    // ...
}
```

### Subscriptions Entity:

```
class Subscriptions
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Trainings" , inversedBy="subscriptions_lists")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_training", referencedColumnName="id",onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $id_training;
```

### QueryBuilder:

```
$trainings = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Trainings')
    ->createQueryBuilder('t')
    ->innerJoin('t.subscriptions_lists', 'subscription')
    ->orderBy('COUNT(subscription.id)', 'DESC')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

I'm getting this exception:

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 87: Error: Expected known function, got 'COUNT'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a field containing the count value and after order by It

try this:

```
$trainings = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Trainings')
    ->createQueryBuilder('t');

$trainings->select('t, COUNT(subscription.id) AS mycount')
    ->leftJoin('t.subscriptions_lists', 'subscription')
    ->groupBy('subscription.id_training')
    ->orderBy('mycount', 'DESC')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

Comment: your solution will return only one array contains the first training, so i just added :  ->groupBy('subscription.id_training') to return the list of trainings with "mycount" .
But the problem when "mycount" == 0 , the training it's not considred, inner join will not consider it ..
so the query result will not contain trainings how does not contain subscriptions

Comment: It works with inner join,some explanations about the diff between innerJoin , leftJoin and join plz?

Comment: Here there is a big answer to your question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join

if this answer has helped you accept It to help other person with your same problem please @Bhs

Comment: Glad to help you! @Bhs

Comment: You can also use `SELECT COUNT(subscription.id) as HIDDEN myacount` if you don't need the count in the result. You will still be able to sort by it.